# Sails.js / Waterline: nested update (or nested 'createOrUpdate')

Tags: javascript, node.js, associations, sails.js, waterline

When creating/updating a record, if I pass a nested object, Sails will create a new record and association between the parent record and the new record. If I pass a string, it will create an association between the parent record and an existing record with that primary key.

The problem: I don't know if a record exists when creating these associations, so I would ideally like pass a nested object and if that record exists, create an association only and if it doesn't exist, create a new record and association.

Is this currently possible with Sails? If not, should it be? To accomplish this now, I have created a helper method that is a chain of promises that will findOrCreate each association first, then use the primary keys to create the associations.